# JavaFX: TextField "datalist"

Tags: java, javafx-2, textfield, datalist

Is it possible to define some kind of "datalist" in JavaFX for the TextField object?

For example, in HTML it is possible to have an "Input" object with type "Text" (~TextField in JavaFX) that has a "datalist" associated with it. This is the list that pops up under the text field while inputting text that most of the time suggests things you've inputted before (e.g. your (e-mail)address) in that textfield.

So, I'm wondering if there is some kind of way to achieve the same thing in JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

have look at these links these may help u...

https://code.google.com/p/jfx-autocomplete-textfield/

and

http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/08/13/source-code-of-autofill-textbox-released/